# How to stop required field validation for master page's textbox at the time of submitting default form

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

When i try to submit the form which is in the default page but same time master page Textbox alerts for input. How to avoid this required field validation.?

Comment: Please add code snippet for others to help

Comment: Use `ValidationGroup` on the validators and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If the field on the Master Page is never required, removing the validator from that field will avoid the issue.

If the field on the Master Page  is required, but not when the controls on the page postback, then set a different ValidationGroup for the buttons/fields on the page and on the Master Page. ValidationGroups allow you to validate multiple groups of controls depending on which control triggers the postback. They can even be set programmatically, making them very flexible.